# Syntax error in HAP SetAttributeValue or mistake in code

Tags: c#, syntax-error, html-agility-pack

```
imgs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
HtmlNode img in imgs    

string imageIdString = image.Id.ToString();
img.SetAttributeValue("src", "/ImageBrowser/ImageById/" + imageIdString);
```

I get a proper value for the ID, but the img source stays unchanged and I can't find why

tried to manage it like here:
[Need to replace an img src attrib with new value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109808/need-to-replace-an-img-src-attrib-with-new-value)

Edit1: The requested code

```
        string input = sectionEditModel.Content;
        string htmlstring = sectionEditModel.Content;
        string htmlstringdecoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlstring);
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        List<string> urls = new List<string>();
        DbImgBrowser.Models.Image image = null;
        doc.LoadHtml(htmlstringdecoded);
        var files = new FilesRepository();


        HtmlNodeCollection imgs = new HtmlNodeCollection(doc.DocumentNode);
        imgs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
        if (imgs != null && imgs.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (HtmlNode img in imgs)
                {
                    HtmlAttribute srcs = img.Attributes[@"src"];
                    urls.Add(srcs.Value);
                    {

                        foreach (string Value in urls){

                            string AttrVal = img.GetAttributeValue("src", null);
                            if(AttrVal.Contains("base64"))
                            {
                                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(Value.Substring(Value.IndexOf(",") + 1));

                                var pFolder = files.GetFolderByPath(string.Empty);
                                if (pFolder != null)
                                {
                                    image = new DbImgBrowser.Models.Image()
                                    {
                                        Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                                        Folder = pFolder,
                                        Image1 = data
                                    };
                                    files.Db.Images.Add(image);
                                    files.Db.SaveChanges();

                                    string imageIdString = image.Id.ToString();
                                    img.SetAttributeValue("src", "/ImageBrowser/ImageById/" + imageIdString);

                                    files.Db.SaveChanges();
                                }
                            }
```

Edit2: Example paths: before base64 example image
Path by Url example /ImageBrowser/Image?path=Test2.PNG

Wanted Result src="ImageBrowser/ImageById/"ID" (1-1000)

Edit3: Still all src is not changed

Comment: Can you post what your input html is and what the expected output should be?

Comment: Input comes from kendo ui editor and includes two kinds of images, either src=url by path or src=base64.
My code catches both cases, writes the information into a byte array which is stored in the Db.
There I get an ID (image.Id) and I want that I can replace the src information with a link to the image. 
So src="ImageBrowser/ImageById/ + Number of Picture in Db. The ID is fine, but when I check by loading the picture again in the browser it still has the base64/url by path src.

Comment: Can you cleanup/post more of your code? The `SetAttributeValue` is used to change the attribute value of the selected node and works for me.

Comment: Posted the whole code of the mentioned part. Would be quite interesting what is the issue.

Comment: Would you also be able to include a couple sample image path src values to run with/step through the code?

Comment: Yea sure.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple.
I was on a local doc but I had to return it to the content and save the section

```
SectionsRepository.SaveSection(Section sec)
```